# Neo4j web cannot be accessed in browser after installing 3.4.0 version

Tags: neo4j, installation, spring-data-neo4j

Previously i have installed `Neo4j-3.1.4` everything was working fine, For upgrade i uninstalled `3.1.4` and again freshly installed `Neo4j-3.4.0`.

I can check status of Neo4j after starting. It shows **running**.

But i cannot access in browser using `http://localhost:7474/browser`

or `http://<ip address>:7474/browser`

I have changed necessary details in **neo4j.conf** file.
Still helpless.

Here is my neo4j.conf changes

```
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=<ip address>:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows on cmd try  ipconfig
 And get you ip adress and go directly to step 4.

If you are on linux, you have to check your network (on linux)

1- cd /etc/network

then apply

2- ifconfig -a

you should have on inet an ip adress matching yours. 
If the adress on inet match your adress ip then check
if the adress on inet match your adress ip then check

3) on linux

cd /etc/neo4j/

sudo nano neo4j.conf

and check on the config file, you have to see if the right configuration is correct.

4) Try with this configuration.

```
on linux 
cd /etc/neo4j/
sudo nano neo4j.conf
```

and check on the file, you have to see if the right configuration is correct.

```
#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true

#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
```

Save config file and restart neo4j.

From browser try Youripaddress:7474/browser/

Comment: That will work if you are using a REMOTE neo4j server.  are you using your browser request    (i.e Youripaddress:7474/browser/ ) from the same machine where neo4j  is installed? or are you using your browser request    (i.e Youripaddress:7474/browser/ ) from  other machine  where neo4j  is not installed but installed on remote machine?  what I described before will work for the second case (i.e when neo4j server is in remote machine).

Comment: Tried with both the cases. It was not working. Then rebooted my machine and installed everything newly. Now works fine. I guess issue was with purge command tht did not remove all dependencies of neo4j while uninstalling